# Number format construct?

Tags: c++

Outside the binary `01010`, octal `01122`, decimal integer `1234` and hexadecimal `0xFF`, does any one have any idea or trick **how to build a new number format**? For example, **`0x11AEGH`** has it's range from **`0`** - **`9`** to **`A`** - **`H`**. I'm going to build password generator, so it would be very helpful if anyone can put something on it that might help.

Firstly, Is there any function which can do this? Basically I want to convert `0x11AEGH` to binary, octal, integer and so on...

Comment: Those are all just representations of numbers that use different bases - 2, 8, 10, and 16, respectively. It sounds like you're just looking for different prefixes to denote numbers in other bases. I don't see how this is particularly relevant to a password generator.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be necessary. If you're generating a password, you could just make an array of all of the characters you want included. Binary, octal, decimal, and hex are just ways to denote integers using convenient representations.

Comment: @xersi What would it mean to "build a new number format"? How are you not just converting a string representation (which is what those other things are) into a difference base representation? What does this have to do with passwords?

Comment: I'm making my own database (binary). If an user want to read it, the user must enter the right encrypted code. (I'll format it using random number format)

Comment: @xersi ... What does that even mean, "format it using random number format"? You'll have to convert it back to something. Have you considered using actual encryption instead of some simplistic thing based on something that is essentially the same as no encryption at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting a number in an N-ary system requires two things: an alphabet, and an ability to obtain results of integer division + the remainder.

Consider formatting a number in a base-26 system using the Latin alphabet. Repeatedly obtain the remainder `R` of division by 26, pick letter number `R`, and add it to the front of the number that you are formatting. Integer-divide the number by 26, and use it in the next step of the algorithm. Stop when you reach zero.

For example, if you print `1234` in base-26, you can do it like this:

- 1234 % 26 is 12. Add `M`; 1234/26 is 47
- 47 % 26 is 21. Add `V`; 47 / 26 is 1
- 1 % 26 is 1. Add `B`. 1 / 26 is zero; stop.

So `1234` in base-26 is `BVM`.

To convert back, start from the front, and sequentially subtract the designated "zero" (`A` in case of the above example) from each digit, like this:

- `B`-`A` is 1. Result is `1`
- `V`-`A` is 21. Result is 1*26+21, which is 47
- `M`-`A` is 12. Result is 47*26+12, which is 1234.

Comment: @xersi More code than what? This is how you convert between bases. What *specific* information are you looking for?

Comment: @xersi do you want to try to write this function?  If you do and get stuck, you can get help here.  If you don't, just say so.

Comment: @xersi If this isn't enough of a description about how this algorithm works I'd *really* recommend not even considering trying to do anything related to encryption beyond using an existing encryption library. There are a ton of reference materials about doing number base conversions.

Comment: @xersi I strongly encourage you to try implementing this algorithm by yourself. It is not hard - there's a loop and little string manipulation. Once you are done, take a look [at my implementation](http://ideone.com/DvV3cl) and compare it to yours.

Comment: Then how to convert back `BVM` to integer?

Comment: Wow, it's now working! And, if I'm going to add the symbol table `0` - `9`, is it possible?

Comment: @xersi Absolutely! The algorithm is generic. In fact, it works the same for the familiar bases, such as two (replace the alphabet with `"01"`), eight (the alphabet is `"01234567"`), and so on. Simply replace 26 with the actual number of "Letters" in your alphabet, and the conversion is going to work both ways. Also take a look at the [base-64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), it uses an alphabet of 64 letters/digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use functions like [Long.parseLong(String representation, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and `Long.toString(long value, int radix)` as they are in Java. Other languages may also have the similar features.

This approach restricts the maximal possible radix (base) and you have no control over the  characters representing different digits (alphanumeric chars are used). However it is a ready solution without any extra coding.